# What different between the two way in array?

Tags: php, arrays

```
<?php
//I have an array like this
$ar = array('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5');

for($i = 0; $i < count($ar); $i++)
{
echo $ar[$i+1]; //way1
echo $ar[$i] +=1 //way2
}

?>
```

So is it different between way1 and way 2 because i saw the same result ???

Answer (score 2):

Here the difference is to use Assignment operator and Increment Operator.

**In a first way :**

$ar[$i+1] will print array element at the index of `$i + 1`, It means 1 in first iteration of loop.

```
echo $ar[$i + 1];
     $ar[0 + 1];
     $ar[1];
```

So It will look for the value of index 1 and that is 1.

**Notice:** While looping, when loop reach to last iteration then your statement will look like this:

```
echo $ar[$i + 1];
     $ar[5 + 1];
     $ar[6];
```

It will show a notice for undefined index because index 6 is not assigned any value in your array.

**In a second way :**

Here increment operator is used. So the statement will become like this:

```
echo $ar[$i] = $ar[$i] + 1;
```

So first, 1 will be added to $ar[$] and then assign to it. And Then after it will echo that updated value. In first iteration of loop it will be:

```
echo $ar[$i] = $ar[$i] + 1;
     $ar[$i] =  0      + 1;

finally Ans will be 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please clarify what exactly you're looking for here.

These two are totally different approaches and give you different results when your array values are something else.

```
echo $ar[$i+1];  // Means you're printing the values corresponding to array keys 1, 2, 3.....

echo $ar[$i] +=1 // Means you're getting the values of keys 0, 1, 2... and adding 1 to each of the values.
```

If you have an array $ar = array(3, 6, 2, 10), these two will work this way:

```
echo $ar[$i+1]; // 6, 2, 10 ....

echo $ar[$i] +=1 // 4, 7, 3, 11....
```

Hope this helps.

Peace! xD

Answer (score 0):

of course not.

Notice, your code need  `";"`  after `way2`

`way1` echo the `(i+1)`-th item in the array.

`way2` echo the `i-th` item'value `+ 1`

so, if you change the array, the result may be different.

e.g.

```
$ar = array('1','3','4');
```

then,

way 1 will output:

`3,4` and catch a `OutOfRange Exception`(because it asked the `$ar[3]`,which is not exist.)

way2 will output:

```
2,4,5
```